# could not add an image in the right place

Tags: java, libgdx

I have been trying to place the stone photos for a few days. I only achieved something today.
On the x coordinate it worked but unfortunately not on the y coordinate. It's like, when I move the mouse down, the stone moves up. I hope someone could help me at that Problem .

```
if (Gdx.input.isButtonJustPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)) {   
    float x = Gdx.input.getX();
    float y = Gdx.input.getY();
    stage_.addActor(whitestone);
    whitestone.addAction(Actions.moveTo(x-15,y-15));
}
```

Comment: My guess is that Y axis is pointed down (so values of y increase downward). In such case moving down should *increase* value of `y`. So maybe instead of `y-15` it should be `y+15`?

Comment: I've already tried it but unfortunately it didn't work. it's like when i press down, the picture is placed on top, but when i press in the middle of the screen the picture is placed correctly

Comment: The first comment is a little off. The y-15 / y+15 change will just change the offset from where you've touched. Try whitestone.addAction(Actions.moveTo(x-15,-y-15));